# How to read a table from MySQL work bench in colab

Tags: sql, colab

I have referred to various articles on Stack Overflow and external sources but somehow am unable to get answer for this. I would like to read a table from MySQL workbench database into a dataframe in colab.

**$1^{st}$ Method:**

In this method, first line of code is successfully executed.
Note: I have hidden database, table and password name for security reasons.

Source -

```
USER = 'root'
PASSWORD = 'PASSWORD'
DATABASE = 'DATABASE'
TABLE = 'TABLE'
 
connection_string = f'mysql+pymysql://root:PASSWORD/DATABASE' 
 
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(connection_string)
```

**I am getting error for second line of code. Is it because my password ends with @786 or some other reasons.**

```
query = f"SELECT * FROM DATABASE.TABLE"
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_sql_query(query, engine)
```

Error:

```
OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL 
server on '786@3306' ([Errno -2] Name or service not known)") (Background on 
this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
```

**$2^{nd}$ Method:**

In this method, the first line of code is successfully executed.
Note: I have hidden database, table and password name for security reasons.

```
connection_string = 'mysql+pymysql://root:PASSWORD@3306/DATABASE'
connect_args = {'ssl': {'ca': '/content/rds-ca-2015-root.pem'}}

db = create_engine(connection_string, connect_args=connect_args)
```

I am getting error for second line of code.

```
query = """SELECT * FROM DATABASE.TABLE"""

events_df = pd.read_sql(query, con=db)
```

Error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

**My Queries:**
***1)   Why I am getting error for 2nd line of code in both methods?
2)  Is there any workaround or alternative approach / codes where I can successfully connect colab with MySQL database and read table?***